# Is there any mathematical function that can assign weights to different kind of distribution yet preserve proportionality?

Tags: data-visualization, weights

Sorry for a very poorly worded title

My project is primarily for a stylistic display of words to layperson regarding their frequency of occurrences by way of font size. The output only needs to convey

1) Which word is the most frequent

2) Is a particular word more frequent than the other?

I am gunning for a presentable visual effect.

Here is my problem:

I am given an arbitrary list of words and their frequency. The distribution of the actual words and frequency are not known at advance. I want to to assign an appropriate font size to each word with respect to its frequency. A higher frequency word will have a larger font size. So it will be shown more prominently.

There are usually two kind of distributions:

1) A very evenly distributed list.

The frequencies are all within say 1 standard deviation of the mean

2) A very unbalanced list with extreme outliers on both end

I will use python to construct my example:

Here is the situation 1

```
import math


FONT_SIZE=96


def genImage1(wls, maxsize=100, color='red'):
    for wl in wls:
        print "<div style=\"font-size:%d;color:%s\">%s</div>" % (wl[1]/float(maxsize)*FONT_SIZE, color, wl[0])

wl = [['inhuman', 100], ['ironman', 90], ['hulk', 95], ['defenders', 85],
      ['punisher', 80], ['jessica jones', 83], ['daredevil', 80], ['x-men', 76],
      ['wolverine', 73], ['deadpool', 69], ['spiderman', 65], ['magneto', 60],
      ['Jean Grey', 55], ['Captain America', 53], ['Black widow', 49], ['Guardian of Galaxy', 41]];
genImage1(wl, wl[0][1])
```

It is very straightforward and here is the outcome. It is what I expect to see.

[image]

Now here is a second list, a list of uneven distribution

```
wl = [['inhuman', 10000], ['ironman', 3090], ['hulk', 1395], ['defenders', 1285],
      ['punisher', 1180], ['jessica jones', 1083], ['daredevil', 980], ['x-men', 976],
      ['wolverine', 873], ['deadpool', 769], ['spiderman', 665], ['magneto', 60],
      ['Jean Grey', 55], ['Captain America', 53], ['Black widow', 49], ['Guardian of Galaxy', 41]];
```

If I reuse the same routine above, of course it is not going to work

[image]

As you can see, a lot of words simply disappeared because the first word `inhuman` is too large by proportion.

I can use `log` to compress both ends and produce a better result:

```
 def genImage2(wls, maxsize=100, color='red'):
    for wl in wls:
        new_size = math.log(wl[1])/math.log(maxsize ) 
        print "<div style=\"font-size:%d;color:%s\">%s</div>" % (new_size*FONT_SIZE, color, wl[0])
```

[image]

However here is the problem:

The frequency of `defenders` 1285 and that of `spiderman` is 665. I would like them to appear more different in size. With `log`, this proportionality is simply removed (i.e. `defenders` should be roughly twice the size of `spiderman` )

My question:

Is there any mathematical function that can allow me to compress both end of outliers and yet preserve some level of proportionality for the numbers in the middle?

I would use the following chart to explain what I want to achieve:

[image]

Blue line represent the raw data set. Red line represents the ideal transformation of the original data series.  I basically want to bring an outlier more into line while the difference between numbers in between both extreme is still visible to a viewer.

Comment: I find the phrase "compress both ends of outliers" confusing (you seem to be using the first and last words in two different senses each there, for example), and it's also not clear exactly what you mean by "preserve proportionality" in the title and near the end when you say "this proportionality is simply removed". Proportional to *what* exactly? It can't be to the original count as you're deliberately choosing to avoid that. Can you draw a plot of font size (as a number) against frequency for each example and add a drawing over the top (perhaps by hand) that illustrates what you seek?

Comment: Regarding `this proportionality is simply removed` I mean I want to be able to show the audience `defenders` is actually different from `spiderman` (`defenders` is twice the size). I will try come up with a plot

Comment: I have added a plot to the question.

Comment: Have you actually looked at what the font sizes corresponding to your red curve look like? ... you may be surprised.

Comment: Perhaps a sigmoid function would be helpful here?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function It wouldn't really "preserve proportionality" across the whole range, but it might achieve the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It kind of sounds like you're after a transformation that reduces the size of very large values but less strongly than logarithms.

There's a large number of possibilities, but perhaps you might consider something in a class of power transformations. In particular, sometimes with counts square roots may be convienient (though with the sort of data you're talking about you may want something a little stronger).

At the same time, you may want to add a linear transformation on the end so that the largest and smallest values fit in with your perception of how much the size should change overall. That is, rather than just take square-roots, rescale so that the largest and smallest font sizes fit some predetermined idea of their relative size (perhaps that the smallest point size is between 35 and 50% of the largest, or something like that).

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Is there any example of power transformation?

Comment: Unfortunately my internet has gone out. The edits I made to the above won't post and my access will be limited for a few days. Having looked at your data I think you may have a different problem to the one I originally thought from your post.

Comment: Looks like it's back now; I may be able to reconstruct the edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort! Really appreciate